# Is it safe to use setInterval in nodejs server environment?

Tags: setinterval, ntp

I am currently implementing a nodejs countdown timer.

I have a client who requests for the remaining time that the server maintains(timer), and client also has a countdown timer too.

Upon implementing client-side countdown timer, I've read many articles and suggestions that we should never use `setInterval` in the browser, since it could be inaccurate. so I am using [react-countdown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-countdown) for measuring accurate countdown.

So I also tried to search in which approach is the best to implement nodejs countdown timer too. But many answers in stackoverflow suggest to use `setInterval`.

Is it pretty accurate to use setInterval in nodejs side?

appreciate in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4):

`setInterval()`, like `setTimeout()`, doesn't guarantee accurate timing. It guarantees *minimum* timing. The callback is invoked *after* the given delay. But it might be invoked a while after the delay. If you assume `setInterval()` is calling your function right on time you'll end up with clock that runs slow.

You can still build a timer using `setInterval()`. But don't use the delay for timing, use it as the polling interval and instead check the system clock.

Like this:

```
const seconds = () => Math.floor(Date.now()/1000)
let then = seconds()
const started = then

function timer() {
  const now = seconds()
  if (then != now) { // We're in a new second.
    console.log(now-started)
    then = now
  }
}

setInterval(timer, 100)
```

The `timer()` function runs 10 times per second. The `console.log()` inside the function runs once each second.

But this only happens approximately. In normal conditions it'll take a little over 1000ms to display the next tick with the occasional 900ms catchup. But it can easily take *much* longer — even many seconds — depending on what else is happening in your code (or on the system).

As an example, put this line after the code above:

```
setTimeout(() => {while(seconds()-started < 5) {}}, 2000)
```

It'll block Node's event loop until the conditional turns false. As `setInterval()` depends on the event loop, `timer()` misses a bunch of seconds. While this is an arbitrary example, it's not uncommon for the event loop to be delayed while other things are going on.

In general there is no mechanism to guarantee timer accuracy within Node.js. Or, for that matter, *any* programming system running on "regular" Linux, Windows, MacOS, etc. For that sort of functionality you need to run an [RTOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system) and even then there are substantial caveats.

But that's a pretty rare need.  For plenty of applications `setInterval()` is more than adequate.